# Can return directly a component from a handling event function in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I have a form to add a category. I expect that when clicking on the add button, there is a notification showing in the corner screen if the input is empty. My idea is returning a Çomponent( or function) contains a toast in `handleAddNewCategory()` but it's not showing. I know that the library react-bootstrap can do showing toast like this

```
handleAddNewCategory(){
if(condition)
  return toastr.info("message",...);
}
```

but I don't want to use it for now. Can anyone give me a solution to solve this with using only bootstrap. I'm totally new to Reactjs.

This is some minimal file:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import AddNewCategory from "./AddNewCategory";
import Notification from "./Notification";

class CategoryList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      categoryNameInput: "",
      categoryDescriptionInput: "",
    };
  }
  ...
  handleAddNewCategory = () => {
    const { categoryNameInput, categoryDescriptionInput } = this.state;
    if (categoryNameInput.trim() === "") {
      return <Notification message="Please enter category name" />;
    }
    if (categoryDescriptionInput.trim() === "") {
      return <Notification message="Please enter category description" />;
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        ...
          <AddNewCategory handleAddNewCategory={this.handleAddNewCategory} />
        ...
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default CategoryList;
```

Notification component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Notification extends Component {
  render() {
    const myStyle = {
      zIndex: "1001",
      position: "absolute",
      top: "10px",
      right: "10px",
    };
    return (
      <div className="toast col-2" style={myStyle} data-autohide="false">
        <div className="toast-header">
          <strong className="mr-auto text-primary">Notice</strong>
        </div>
        <div className="toast-body">{this.props.message}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Notification;
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.toast').toast('show');
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't use jquery to show the toast it's not the best practice and instead of conditionally rendering the component what you can do is. just render it ones and then controlled its visibility.

follow the below code:-

Notification component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Notification extends Component {
 render() {
 const myStyle = {
  zIndex: "1001",
  position: "absolute",
  top: "10px",
  right: "10px",
 };
 return (
  <div hidden={this.props.showToast} className="toast col-2" style={myStyle} data-autohide="false">
    <div className="toast-header">
      <strong className="mr-auto text-primary">Notice</strong>
    </div>
    <div className="toast-body">{this.props.message}</div>
  </div>
 );
}
}
export default Notification;
```

Notification component usage :-

```
class CategoryList extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    categoryNameInput: "",
    categoryDescriptionInput: "",
    toastMessage:'',
    showToast:false
  };
 }
...
handleAddNewCategory = () => {
  const { categoryNameInput, categoryDescriptionInput } = this.state;
  if (categoryNameInput.trim() === "") {
    this.setState({
     toastMessage:'Please enter category name',
     showToast:true
    })

  }
  if (categoryDescriptionInput.trim() === "") {
     this.setState({
       toastMessage:'Please enter category name',
       showToast:true
     })
  }
};
render() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Notification message={this.state.toastMessage} showToast={this.state.showToast}/>;
      ...
        <AddNewCategory handleAddNewCategory={this.handleAddNewCategory} />
      ...
    </div>
  );
}
}
export default CategoryList;
```

here what i do is i initialise the boolean in state and enable it so that toast will be visible and i pass it directly throw props so that whenever your message and boolean changes it automatically reflects in your notification controller.

> and to remove the toast just set {showToast} to false whenever you want. and remove the jquery part from your code

Comment: oh thank you, I got it. They just render once and we use the state to set it's visibility. I will try